# How to access logback.xml from external folder

Tags: tomcat6, logback, weblogic-10.x

I'm using logback API for logging in my project but requirement is there will be single logback.xml configuration file for  two project and logback.xml should be access from outside of project.

I have placed logback.xml in my project class path and this is working fine. Can any body suggest me how can I access logging configuration file from external folder?

Answer (score 0):

You might find section of the Logback FAQ helpful: [Is it possible for multiple JEE applications to share the same configuration file but without stepping on each other's toes?](http://logback.qos.ch/faq.html#sharedConfiguration)

In short, you can use any configuration file you want (provided that your Java application can access it) using `JoranConfigurator.doConfigure("/path/to/your/config/file.xml")`. HTH!